# Attach a PDF file from XHTML file to Email

Tags: java, pdf

I have a JSP page, and I'm trying to develop new functionality to generate a PDF from that JSP page to send it as attachment to users.

I was able to covert the JSP to velocity template and send it as an HTML file to users, but when I'm trying to use the fly source lib to send PDF attachment I'm getting(Failed to load PDF document) to that attachment file.

here's what I'm trying to do,

```
try {
                MimeMessage mm = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
                MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mm,true);
                helper.setSentDate(new Date());
                helper.setSubject(subject);
                helper.setFrom(from);
                helper.setTo(to.trim()); 

                LOG.debug("**Getting  here");
                Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<>();
                model.put("date", new DateTool());

                //Get the report as html
                String xmltoConvert = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine,
                        "toConvert.xhtml", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name(), model);



// tring to convert xhtml to PDF
                    ByteArrayResource htmlBytes = new ByteArrayResource(xmltoConvert.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
                     final ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    org.w3c.dom.Document document = XMLResource.load(new ByteArrayInputStream(xmltoConvert.getBytes())).getDocument();
                    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
                    renderer.setDocument( document, null );
                    renderer.layout();
                    renderer.createPDF(byteArrayOutputStream);
                    renderer.finishPDF();
                    byteArrayOutputStream.close();
                    helper.addAttachment(subject + ".pdf", htmlBytes);
                    javaMailSender.send(mm);
                }
```

Can you please help here, what I'm I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to pass the  byteArrayOutputStream not the htmlBytes ..

```
 helper.addAttachment(subject + ".pdf",
                                new ByteArrayResource(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()));
```